# Why the value changes on MySQL different versions?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, sqldatatypes

I got an export of a MySQL table  (version 5.7.42) containing a `bit(15)` column named `permissions`, the value was shown like this: `111111101110111`. I imported that dump to a new MySQL server (version 8.0.34), now the value of that column is shown like this: `32767`.

So, why `111111101110111` has converted to `32767` after export/import? Also, how can I make it back to `1` and `0` model? You know, each character of that value means an accessibility for my project. Please take a look at this code:

```
IF (IFNULL((@permission & b'1000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "No access to leave a comment";
END IF;
```

Comment: `111111101110111` in base 2 is equal to `32767` in base 10. No matter the visual representation you get (base x), what worth is the value

Comment: Also, I would use database normalization to manage access rights (`users`, `permissions`, `users_permissions` tables)

Comment: @Cid: equivalent to 32767? Why: https://dbfiddle.uk/GPJclQhd ? (I do see `32631`)

Comment: @Luuk Actually I modified the bit value by hand and it's my bad. `32767` is the same as all 15-bit of `1`.

Comment: OK, when someone is looking at the numbers in the question) see: `select b'111111111111111', convert(b'111111111111111', signed), bin(32767);`

Comment: How was the "export/import" done?  If it was via `mysqldump`, what is in that file?  This seems to be where the problem is.

Comment: Well, 111111101110111 is actually 32631, but all the discussion is still valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion from `111111101110111` to `32767` is happening because the value is being treated as a 15-bit integer, and the binary representation `111111101110111` is indeed equivalent to the integer `32767`.

In MySQL 8.0, the `BIT` data type represents the number as a binary string in certain contexts (like when fetching the value from a result set in some clients), but in other contexts, it might treat it as an integer. The inconsistency may cause confusion.

You can convert the integer value back to a binary string using the following SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT BIN(permissions + 0) AS permissions FROM your_table;
```

Adding `0` ensures that the value is treated as a number, and then `BIN` converts it to a binary string.

To make it look like a 15-character string, you may need to pad it with leading zeros. You can do this with the `LPAD` function:

```sql
SELECT LPAD(BIN(permissions + 0), 15, '0') AS permissions FROM your_table;
```